# Working (particles.js) animate backgroung don't display on GitHub hosting

Tags: github, hosting, particles.js

I done with my profile page, but animation don't want to run on GitHub hosting. Here is a link [rmb-dev.github.io](http://rmb-dev.github.io). Other content and CSS animation working well except JavaScript. Can't find the reason why.

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 100,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area":1000
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": ["#0892d0", "#f6f930"]
    },

    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#fff"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.6,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 120,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
#particles-js {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #282828;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="RMB" content="/85">
    <title>RMB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>


        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/particles.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console, there is a message telling mixed active content is blocked: I got particles.min.js via http, but the page is https.

Most CDNs allow an https access, so I fixed that.